# Is there are a way to change the breaks of a ggplot legend without changing other properties of the aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to change the breaks of a ggplot legend without affecting the other properties of the aesthetic (e.g., palette, name, etc.). For example, a MWE where the aesthetic is `colour`:

```
## Original plot:
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = 1:10)
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral", name = "Original title")
gg

## Plot with adjusted breaks:
gg + scale_colour_distiller(breaks = c(2.5, 7.5))
```

[Original plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wufq7.png)

[Plot with adjusted breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoZap.png)

In the second plot, the colour palette and the legend name are reset to their default values: I want to change the legend breaks only.

I understand why the above approach does not work; the first colour scale is completely replaced by the second scale. However, I don't know how to tackle this problem. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use all arguments inside only one function? 
 scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral", name = "Original title", breaks = c(2.5,7.5))

Comment: I need to change the breaks *after* the plot has been created. Should have mentioned that in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function which solves my question. It takes a `ggplot` object, the name of an aesthetic (as a string), and the `breaks` for the corresponding legend.

```
change_legend_breaks <- function(gg, aesthetic, breaks) {

  ## Find the scales associated with the specifed aesthetic
  sc <- as.list(gg$scales)$scales
  all_aesthetics <- sapply(sc, function(x) x[["aesthetics"]][1]) 
  idx <- which(aesthetic == all_aesthetics) 
  
  ## Overwrite the breaks of the specifed aesthetic
  gg$scales$scales[[idx]][["breaks"]] <- breaks
  
  return(gg)
}
```

This is my first time dealing with ggplot objects at a low level, so perhaps there is a better, more robust approach: This works for me, though.
Interestingly, it seems to be a mutating function, that is, it alters the plot object itself, rather than a copy of the object. I didn't know this was possible in R.

As a check that the function works as intended, here is a variant on the original MWE, this time with two aesthetics:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z1 = 1:10, z2 = 1:10)
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z1, size = z2)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_size(name = "Original size title") + 
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral", name = "Original colour title") 

change_legend_breaks(gg, "colour", breaks = c(2.5, 7.5))
change_legend_breaks(gg, "size", breaks = c(1, 9))
```